# In Postgres, how do you insert possible values for a particular column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table name **ar** for column operation in it I can allow only specific values ('C', 'R', 'RE', 'M', 'P'). I have added a check constraint for it.

**Requirement**:
I need to insert 1 million records in the table but operation column has a constraint that only specific values are allowed. I am using generate_series() to generate values which generates random values and throws error. **How can I avoid the error and insert 1 million record with only the required values ('C', 'R', 'RE', 'M', 'P') in column named operation.**

```
CREATE TABLE ar (
  mappingId TEXT,
  actionRequestId integer,
  operation text,
  CONSTRAINT chk_operation CHECK (operation IN ('C', 'R', 'RE', 'M', 'P'))
);
```

```
INSERT INTO ar (mappingId, actionRequestId, operation)
SELECT substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 10),
       (random() * 70 + 10)::integer,
       substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 10)
FROM generate_series(1, 1000000);
```

```
ERROR: new row for relation "ar" violates check constraint "chk_operation"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a cross join with the allowed values:

```
INSERT INTO ar (mappingid, actionrequestid, operation)
SELECT substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 10),
       (random() * 70 + 10)::integer, 
       o.operation
FROM generate_series(1, 1000000 / 5)
   cross join ( 
     values ('C'), ('R'), ('RE'), ('M'), ('P')
   ) as o(operation);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO ar (mappingId, actionRequestId, operation)
 SELECT substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 10),
   (random() * 70 + 10)::integer,
  'C'
FROM generate_series(1, 200000)
 UNION ALL
SELECT substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 10),
   (random() * 70 + 10)::integer,
  'R'
FROM generate_series(1, 200000)
 UNION ALL
SELECT substr(md5(random()::text), 1, 10),
   (random() * 70 + 10)::integer,
  'RE'
FROM generate_series(1, 200000)
```

Comment: The above solution works. But is bounds to re-modifying the query every time. For example, the list of required values will be different and can increase or decrease in different environment (dev, production). Can we make a generic solution to fetch from list of required values (values can be anything. Not known in advance but will be limited for each environment). So, there is no need to rely on hard-coded values for operation column.

Comment: Then please use solution by  a_horse_with_no_name